# Android Unforunately App has stopped

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest

I am using 2 menu items, first menu item to send *Global Greeting* & second item for *Settings*,
whenever i click on **Settings** menu item, i am always getting below message:

**Unfortunately App has Stopped**

Logcat Says:

```
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.january.floogoo/android.media.audiofx.BassBoost$Settings}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromChild(Activity.java:3843)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromChild(Activity.java:3819)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3395)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at com.january.floogoo.ContactTab.onOptionsItemSelected(ContactTab.java:90)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2548)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:980)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.onItemClick(ListMenuPresenter.java:166)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-03 16:20:38.102: E/AndroidRuntime(953):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.january.floogoo.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ContactTab"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MonthTab"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".WeekTab"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".PersonalGreeting"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".GlobalGreeting"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AlertPage"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Settings"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Alert2"></activity>
```

Comment: your activity is not in your manifest (which, incidentally, is what the error says)

Comment: you'll want to post the content of com.january.floogoo.ContactTab.onOptionsItemSelected(ContactTab.java:90)

Comment: add entire manifest file here not only the activity tags

Comment: your package name is wrong

Comment: @njzk2 I have read in manifest, but i am surprise why i am getting this because i am using Settings activity in my manifest, and you can see above

Comment: @Rajesh buddy what is wrong in my package name??\

Comment: post the code for ContactTab.onOptionsItemSelected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare Settings Activity As in Manifest :

```
 <activity android:name="com.january.floogoo.Settings" />
```

and start Settings Activity using full package name because you have imported another package with same Activity name

```
 Intent intentd=new Intent(Current_Activity.this,
                              com.january.floogoo.Settings.class);
 startActivity(intentd);
```

Comment: unlikely. As the stacktrace suggests, the packagename is com.january.floogoo

Comment: @njzk2 : see `com.january.floogoo/android.media.audiofx.BassBoost$Settings` also from stacktrace

Comment: @njzk2 : right is `com.january.floogoo/com.january.floogoo$Settings`

Comment: @njzk2 : and if setting Activity is in other packge then i think OP register it as `<activity android:name="android.media.audiofx.BassBoost.Settings" />`

Comment: this is very possible, well seen. The BassBoost.Settings is an android class that could have been imported by mistake

Comment: @njzk2 : important point is that OP is not sending proper intent for starting Setting Activity

Answer (score 0):

You already had `Setting` activity in your manifest, but I think with wrong package name.
Try setting it using full package name like `com.january.floogoo.Settings`.